# How can I use node.js to read a text file of nouns and store it in a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, storage, bots

So I am trying to write a bot that posts to Facebook, "You wouldn't (random verb) a (random noun), would you?" every hour. I have a long list verbs and nouns entitled, "verbs.txt" and "nouns.txt". What I am having trouble with is getting the program to read the files, choose a random word from the files, and store it in a variable. I have tried quite a few different things, to no results, I've walked my code back to this version would run, save for the undefined variables.

```
let postContents = "You wouldn't" + verb + " a " + noun + ", would you?";

FB.api('me/feed', 'post', { message: postContents }, res => {
    if (!res || res.error) {
        return console.error(!res ? 'error occurred' : res.error);
    }

    console.log(`Post ID: ${res.id}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming files look like:

```
noun
noun1
```

You can load this in as such. This is in a synchronous way. You could also do this in an asynchronous way if desired.

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const nounFile = "nouns.txt";
const verbFile = "verbs.txt";

const readFile = function (file) {
    return fs.readFileSync(file).toString().split("\n");
};

const randomItem = function (items) {
    return items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];
};

const nouns = readFile(nounFile);
const verbs = readFile(verbFile);
const noun = randomItem(nouns);
const verb = randomItem(verbs);
```

Comment: Ah, Shawn, my guy, you are a boss ass king thank you so much, you are my hero. Right now it is posting the entire list of nouns I have. Is it because of how I have my text file organized? Right now it is done with one word to a line and a line between all the words.

Comment: I should have clarified, the nouns are not one noun to a file, it is a list of nouns in a single file labeled 'nouns.txt'

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out, thank you so much for your help